# Data suddenly becomes NULL in debug builds

Tags: c++, debugging

I have a process that calls functions from a DLL, inside the DLL I allocate a structure, the structure is used in the different functions inside the DLL, and always passed by reference to those function when called (by the process).
most of the time things are fine, but when I do a debug build (using Visual Studio 2008), many times, the process will crash, because that structure becomes suddenly NULL
the situation is like this:

- Process calls Func1 , which allocates the structure and initialize
  variables
- Process calls Func2 , it does some processing on the    structure,
  modifies some variables...
- Process calls Func3 , I use the    structure in many places, then at
  one place inside the code (where I    am assigning a string (
  std::string myStr = myStructre->myStrucString)    the process crashed
  with access violation error... I check with the    debugger to find that
  myStructure with all its variables is suddenly    NULL....

Any Idea ?! (its very very rare with release build)

Comment: Is this structure pointer/variable global and being accessed through another global pointer/variable. You need to make sure you are not a victim Static Initialization Fiasco.

Comment: You know code is much less ambiguous than a description in English of the code.

Comment: @LokiAstari true, but the code is thousands of lines...

Comment: Am afraid it has something to do with strings, it only happens while assigning or comparing strings...

Comment: @aiman09: Then I would suggest you make the code as small as possable that still reproduces the problem and post it here. The processes of making the code smaller will probably result in you finding the bug. Without the code all people are doing is guessing which is a pointless activity.

Comment: @aiman09: Also make sure your code compiles with zero warning with the warning level turned up. This will show up all places were the code is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try using [data breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to find out where it is modified.